# MS Access - trying to use a UNION ina query inserting data into a table

Tags: ms-access, union

I have a history table that I am trying to insert data into.  The data in the source table is horizontal i need the data vertical.  In order to do this, I run 36 queries.  I would like to run 1 query that has 36 select statements in  it.   I wrote a select query that has a union it it.  it runs fine and i get the data. when i take that query and convert it to an insert into query, i get an error at the UNION clause

Anyone run into this?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the actual SQL that you are trying to run, simplified to a few UNION clauses.

Answer (score 1):

Save your working *union select query* as a query.

Then use this query as source in a new *append query* which will append records to your table.